# How to pass dictionary as a parameter in JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to json, I want to pass dictionary as a parameter along with the url to server, how it can be done while method is post ? Ihad tried sample codes but not found my exact solution.below is my sample code

```
    NSMutableDictionary *callDict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [callDict setObject:@"messages-getModuleMessages" forKey:@"call"];
    [callDict setObject:FB_API_KEY forKey:@"accessSecret"];
    NSString *x=[FBUserManager sharedUserManager].authToken;
    [callDict setObject:x forKey:@"authToken"];
       [callDict setObject:@"json" forKey:@"format"];

    [callDict setObject:@"inbox" forKey:@"callType"];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fretbay.com/fr/private/api/rest-server.php?",calldict]];//here recieving warning

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];     // here parsing the array
```

Comment: those who down voted please mention reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume that these are your `strings`

```
NSString *messages-getModuleMessages=@"messages-getModuleMessages";
NSString * authtincateToken=@"WWc3ZFZCcEtWcGxLTk1hZHhEb2hMelFNZzdGcXgwdTBxeU51NWFwUE44TnkrcnF5SCtSMDxxxxxxx";
NSString *accessSecretkey =@"WWc3ZFZCcEtWcGxLTk1hZHhEb2hMelFNZzdGcXgwdTBxeU51NWFwUE44TnkrcnF5SCtxxxxxxxx";
NSString *inboxvalue =@"hai thios is textmessage";

// this is your dictionary value are you passed
NSDictionary * callDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:messages-getModuleMessages,@"call",authtincateToken,@"authToken", accessSecretkey, @"accessSecret",inboxvalue,@"calotype",@"json",@"format",nil];

  // convert your dictionary to NSData
  NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:callDict options:kNilOptions error:nil];
 // this is your service request url
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxx"]];
 // set the content as format
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
  // this is your response type        
 [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
   NSError *err;
  NSURLResponse *response;
   // send the synchronous connection
   NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
   // here add your server response NSJSONSerialization
  NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err]; 

  // if u want to check the data in console
  NSString *tmp=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", tmp);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
        @"call": @"messages-getModuleMessages",
        @"accessSecret": FB_API_KEY,
        @"authToken": [FBUserManager sharedUserManager].authToken,
        @"format": @"json",
        @"inbox":@"callType"
    };

    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fretbay.com/fr/private/api/rest-server.php?"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *dataTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest: request
            fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put following method to `Call WebService`

```
- (void) callWebservice_Block : (NSDictionary *) jsonDict :(void(^)(NSDictionary * dic, NSError * err))responseHandler{

NSError * err;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&err];
NSString * jsonRequest = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];;

NSLog(@"jsonRequest is %@", jsonRequest);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Past your URL Here"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSData *requestData = [jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        responseHandler (nil,error);

    } else {
        NSDictionary * returnDict  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                   error: &error];
        responseHandler (returnDict,nil);
    }

    }];}
```

you can `Call Method` via following way.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"FirstValue",@"FirstKey",@"SecondValue",@"SecondKey", nil];

[self callWebservice_Block:jsonDict :^(NSDictionary *dic, NSError *err) {
    if(!err){
        NSLog(@"Got Response :- %@",dic);
    }

}];
```